# Xpath issue in element location

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am getting a very long xpath for an element that I selected. Is there anyway to shorten it? This is the xpath I am getting:

```
//li[@class='menu_men 1-level hasChild']//div[contains(@class,'level-2')]//div[@class='menu-wrapper']//ul[@class='level-2']//li[@class='1-level']//div[@class='level-3']//ul[@class='level-3']//li//a[@class='level-3'][contains(text(),'Socks')]
```

This is the URL: [Calvin Klein Singapore](https://www.calvinklein.com/sg) I hovered over 'MEN', the accessories section will appear, than I hover the 'Socks' to get the xPath.

I am getting the following execption in my code and I am wondering if somehow the long xpath could be one of the reasons:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='first
>   menu_men 1-level
>   hasChild']//div[contains(@class,'level-2')]//div[@class='menu-wrapper']//ul[@class='level-2']//li[@class='1-level']//div[@class='level-3']//ul[@class='level-3']//li//a[@class='level-3'][contains(text(),'Socks')]"}

I am using cropath from within chrome developer tools to get the xPath.

I am new to automation, I really hope someone can advise. Thank you.

@SameerArora this is the code I have to clear the pop up window, as what I had mentioned in the comments below.

```
//for clearing the popup window
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//*[starts-with(@id,'popup-subcription-closes-link-')]")
    public WebElement newsletterpopup;  

    public String clickCategory(){
                //.....
                resusableFunctions.buttonClick(driver, newsletterpopup, "popoup");
                }
    public void buttonClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String elementName) throws InterruptedException
        {
            try
            {
                element.click();
                System.out.println("Log: ResuableFunction.buttonClick");
            }
        catch (org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException notInteract)
            {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The element you are looking for can be found using xpath:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Socks')])[1]"));
```

However, as the element is not visible directly when you are opening the link, you would be getting NoSuchElementException, so to resolve it you can use javascript click method on the element which directly operates on the div of the page.
Addition to this, i can see that a subscription popup comes when i am opening the page for the first time, so you need to dismiss that popup first(if the popup is present) and then click on the "Socks" element using the JavaScript click method.

Your code should be like:

```
List<WebElement> closeSubscriptionPopUp = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'popup-subcription-closes-link')]"));
if (closeSubscriptionPopUp.size() > 0) {
    closeSubscriptionPopUp.get(0).click();
}
WebElement sockElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Socks')])[1]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", sockElement);
```

Comment: Did you test your code? The _MEN_ section seems to be a pseudo element.

Comment: @DebanjanB i did check the element, i have uploaded the screenshot with its xpath here: https://imgur.com/6cABT5Q please check and let me know if i have made any mistake somewhere.

Comment: You are validating the  _xpath_ through _Dev Tools_ protocol, hence getting resolved. IMO, _Selenium_ won't be able to resolve it directly through `findElement()` as it is a _pseudo_ element. That's why I asked did you test _programatically_? Checkout once and let us know.

Comment: I did try to run the code, the action class move to element method is working fine but the `click()` method is not getting executed. So, i am updating my answer now. Thanks !!

Comment: `move to element()` for which element? I believe _Socks_ is having the _style_ as **hidden**

Comment: move to the "Men" element was working fine but the selenium `click` method was not working on the "Socks" element. I have used javascript click method now and its working as expected. I have updated my answer as well. Please check. Thanks !!

Comment: Okay, my last suggestion, `click()` would be overhead for _Men_, you just need to _Mouse Hover_. Try using the simple _Java_ functions. Good luck !!!

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry, but i guess i was not been able to explain what i did in my last approach. Let me try again: I was hovering to the "Men" element using the action class method `moveToElement` and then i was using the selenium click method on the `Socks` element. After running the code, i could see that the "Men" section was getting displayed using the `moveToElement` method, but selenium click method on the "Socks" element was not working, so now i have used javascript click directly on the "Socks" element and now its working fine.

Comment: There is no need to feel sorry. You have been contributing for quite some time now and some of your answers were awesome. I simply wanted to push you in the right direction so your answers are helpful to the future readers.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you, means a lot to me and yes i am always trying to improve my concepts and hence my answers :)

Comment: @SameerArora 

Code already exists to handle the pop-up.
 
The print statement in the try block gets printed in the console, and also visually I can see that the pop-up disappears after a few seconds, based on this I am concluding that the code successfully clears the popup. If that is indeed, what else could be the reason for socks not being selected?

Comment: The xpath that you have used is absolute xpath and if there is any change in the html structure, your xpath would not work. So please try the code that i have mentioned in the answer, it will handle the popup as well as will click on the "Socks"element.

Comment: @javaperson did you try the code, did it help you ?

Answer (score 1):

To hovered over 'MEN' >> accessories >> 'Socks' section, You need to use selenium **Actions** class.

As it is not really possible to first click on men(as it will open other section), 
So to hover to sock, you need to chain all of the actions that you want to achieve in one go.

**Process should be:**

1. move to men element first
2. Move to accessories
3. then move to Socks and click on it.

**Note: *By using Action class, we can chain all the process in one single go.
As mentioned below***

**1) First way:**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'MEN')])[2]")))
.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Socks')])[1]")))
.click().build().perform();
```

**2) Second way with wait:**

```
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'MEN')])[2]"))).build().perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Socks')])[1]")));
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Socks')])[1]")));
action.click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the comments here. I am no longer working on this project, but I find automation and selenium to be interesting and will try to find the time to learn more about these technologies. Thank once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//a[normalize-space(text()) = 'Socks']
```

I would recommend you to not use such long xpath's and try to write xpath on your own.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
//li[contains(@class,'menu_men')]//a[contains(text(),'Socks')]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer: what have you changed and why?